# Qt: Font is getting bigger for floating forms and undocked windows on 4K monitor

Tags: qt, font-size

I am working on a existing Qt application and trying to support it on 4K monitor. For scaling the app, I am using "QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR" and scaling fonts based on logical DPI of screen. Everything is fine till this. Fonts for ribbon, docked windows are ok after scaling. But the font is getting too bigger for floating forms (pop up dialogs) and the docked widgets after undocking (the moment window is undocked, font is becoming bigger). I don't understand why this is happening. Is windows taking control over floating forms and making font bigger? Or am I missing something?

I am not using "Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling" or "QT_SCALE_FACTOR" because I did not find these useful for me.

Has anyone faced this kind of problem?
Please let me know if someone knows about this.

Answer (score 0):

After trying this and that, I found a solution to this problem.
I added'**QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_DisableHighDpiScaling);**' before creating QApp. And then I just needed to change the font size.